# How to efficiently maintain a navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how to efficiently maintain a navigation bar. Based on my understanding right now, we just include the html code for the bar at each individual webpage. However, if I had many webpages I would need copy and rewrite the html code for each page. And if I would want to add or remove links I would need to change and update all of the pages. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You might like https://wordpress.org/

Comment: What you are looking for are "templates". But this is a very basic question, I suggest you learn more about web development fundamentals first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways we can achieved this but here are the simplest I can think of right now.

**1. Using PHP include_once function**

You can use php for that. Simply store your navigation in a file called `header.php` for example, then `include_once('header.php');` in your page. Make sure your page have a `.php` extension instead of `.html`

**2. Using jQuery**

If you want to stay with the current language(HTML,CSS,Javascript), you can also use JQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$("#header").load('header.html');
```

It is better to run this after the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#header").load('header.html');
}
```

Somewhere in your code, you should have `<div id="header">` for the script to inject the `nav` in `header.html`

Answer (score -1):

what they do is that they load the page which is called from the server,  besides the navigation bar. like either you can call the page in an `iframe` or you can run a script that could render the elements besides the navigation bar. That's  how they could maintain the navigation bar